# Pulumi azure: assign access policy to keyvault

Tags: pulumi, pulumi-python, pulumi-azure

I want to assign an access policy to the Keyvault without importing the keyvault.
Since importing a resource like keyvault is a real pain, considering you have to list every required property of the KV(100+ lines with a lot of parametrization needed), I would like to do it in a simpler way.

I want to grant access for an sql server to the keyvault using service principal, here is the code I create the access policy:

```
access_policy = keyvault.AccessPolicyEntryArgs(
    object_id       = sp_id,
    tenant_id       = auth.tenant_id,
    permissions     = keyvault.PermissionsArgs(keys=[keyvault.KeyPermissions.GET, keyvault.KeyPermissions.UNWRAP_KEY, keyvault.KeyPermissions.WRAP_KEY])
)
```

How can I assign it to the keyvault? Is there a simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a `get` function on the vault, in this case [`get_vault`](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/azure-native/api-docs/keyvault/getvault/)

```
vault = keyvault.get_vault(resourceGroupName=rg.name, vaultName="my-key-vault")
```